# Is it possible that mysql would fail to update some data?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, let say we have two rows:

`member_id, name`

Let say `member_id` = 15 and `name` = 'John';

I want to UPDATE this data and do the following query:

`mysql_query("UPDATE members SET member_id = 14, name = 'Peter' WHERE member_id = 15`

This is just an example, but is it possible that mysql would fail and UPDATE for example only name row. So, after completing mysql_query above, it would become `member_id` = 15 and `name` = 'Peter';

It is just an example. Today, a similar situation happened in my website and I checked my code hundred times and I see no errors and there hadn't been no same errors before it at all.

So, should I recheck my code one hundred times more, or it can happen?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would become **`member_id = 14`** and `name = 'Peter'`. Correct?

Comment: Does member_id have a key (and an update would cerate a duplicate key)?!

Comment: @ypercube: yes. @freddy K. : it is just an example, i told you.

Comment: Is it possible that member_id was changed to 14 and then some other query changed it back to 15?

Comment: Don't do this. What you're proposing is an upkeep nightmare. And if your member_id column is not an auto increment primary key column you're probably not doing it right. In most cases a member id is also a unique column. This increases your chances of hitting a unique key constraint violation.

Comment: `member_id` and `name` would be *columns*, not *rows*. And the update should not work on one column and not another on the same row, which this would be (one row containing two columns, one column containing the `member_id` and one column containing the `name`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec, single `UPDATE` statements are atomic; ie: either it updates all columns or it doesn't update any of them.

So no, it shouldn't happen. But of course there could be a bug with MySQL.

Comment: thank you. If it is really true, I have absolutely no idea how it hadn't happened before and happened only one time.

Comment: I checked the whole code hundreds of time today and only know, after 10 minute I created this question I finally found where the error was :D Omg, it is so cool to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put `or die(mysql_error());` after your query so that if this really is happening then you would at least know about it.

Comment: it happened one time only - today, and before that there had never been the same error.

Comment: @hey: Until it happens again I really wouldn't worry (but do use `die();` after everything to trap it if it ever chose to)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not happen that it would become member_id = 15 and name = 'Peter'. The SQL syntax is right as far as i can see and it seems all good. If something wrong happens to your database and your query is executed in that moment God only knows what could happen. Despite this, most of the time either the query is executed entirely or it is not, making `mysql_query()` return `false`.

You should, as already suggested at least check if there where any error with a code such as the following if you are in an online business website:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die('An error occurred');
```

or something like as follows if you are in debug mode:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as sure as everyone else that single-row updates are atomic. MySQL differs from standard SQL in that it does the column assignments of a single-table UPDATE left-to-right. That means `member_id = 14` is done before `name = 'Peter'`. If `name = 'Peter'` violates a constraint, or triggers another update that fails, then that assignment will fail. However, whether the statement as a whole fails or not may depend on various factors, including whether the table is using a transaction-safe engine.